# Using ArcPy to shorten polylines of varying lengths by 44% of original length (or by value contained in field)?

Tags: arcpy

I have a feature class containing tens of thousands of polylines of varying lengths that were constructed from only a start and end point (of note, they are all at different angles, and many lines overlap one another).  That said, I also have the original point file if it would be easier to work with.

I am looking for a way to shorten these lines by 44% of their original length.

Perhaps by creating a new point 44% "down the line" from the original starting point, then maybe removing the original end point and then redrawing the line?  Seems like that would work.

Of note,the data are projected, albers_NAD83.  These are just straight lines, ie with a start point and an end point.  The points also contain additional attributes that I would need to retain.

Answer (score 5):

I made a custom [Shorten Polylines toolbox](http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-shorten-polylines-percentage-distance-arcpy/) for you. I only tested it with about 5 lines, but it should do the same with tens of thousands.

It works with ArcGIS 10.1+

It creates new, shortened polylines based on a specified distance or percentage. The value can be fixed or field based. The output contains a field called LineOID, which is the OID of the polyline it was created from.

[View the Source Code](http://ianbroad.com/download/script/ShortenPolylines.py)

And here is a screenshot of the parameters:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you state your lines are straight you could get a handle on each polyline and get the FROM end of the polyline as a point. Then query the polyline to create the TO end point. Combine these 2 points to create your reduced polyline. You could either overwrite the existing geometry or write the new polyline off to a new featureclass with the polyline ID (So you can join the attributes to it).

A polyline has a method for creating a point along a polyline it is called *positionAlongLine*. Look at the Help file to understand the parameters of this.